# Get file descriptor when executing `kprobe:tcp_v4_connect`

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ebpf

I'm writing an eBPF program to track requests from the client-side.
I found that I can get the Host and Port information in the source and destination of the request through `kprobe:tcp_v4_connect`.
But when I want to trace the request information through `tracepoint:syscalls:write`, I find that only one file descriptor is provided. I can't relate the information between connecting and writing.

So I am thinking about how can I get the file descriptor in `tcp_v4_connect`, Or is there a better way to create the request?

Comment: Could you provide more information on your end goal? Like what information you are hoping to collect.

Comment: OK, I want to build request topology through eBPF technology. So I need to specify the requested data and the upstream and downstream host and port information.

I found that `tcp_v4_connect` can get the upstream and downstream host and port information, but when I use `tracepoint:syscalls:write` to intercept and send requests, the information cannot be matched. Because `tcp_v4_connect` cannot find the socket file descriptor, and `tracepoint:syscalls:write` is based on the socket file descriptor. I can't relate to these two.

Comment: What sort of requests are those? HTTP? Did you consider tracing the packets instead and parsing the information you need?

Comment: HTTP is the one type of requests, such as the Redis, MySQL, or other protocols, but they are based on the TCP. No need to parse the packets. I just want to get the local address host and port when connecting to another socket.

Comment: If you just want host and port, why are you trying to intercept writes?